# Objective-c iphone App, problems with button to parsed hyperlink

Tags: iphone, nsstring, uibutton, hyperlink, nsurl

Another problem for me with my application is a simple procedure. I want to have a button which, if you press, opens the link associated with the article in question.  I have followed instructions that i understand, but I am having trouble understanding why the link will not work.

```
- (IBAction)link:(id)sender {
WebViewController *view = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" 
                                                              bundle:nil];
[[self navigationController]pushViewController:view 
                                      animated:YES];
NSString *urlAddress = [item objectForKey:@"link"];
NSLog(@"urlad = %@", urlAddress);
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSLog(@"url = %@", url);
[[view webView] loadRequest:request];

[urlAddress release];
[url release];
[view release];}
```

I have tried investigating this further, but with no luck (The NSLogs).  I can tell that the "link" is getting into the urlAddress string, but the url NSURL will not accept the string conversion.  It is most irritating.

If anyone could help, i would be most grateful.

Comment: So you're saying `urlAddress` is fine, but `url` is `nil`? What does `urlAddress` contain?

Comment: It has been a long time since I checked this query, i should set that it was solved. Thank you for responding though.